# Openshift: Php 5.4 disable zlib compression

Tags: php, apache, openshift, zlib, httpd.conf

I am currently develop an app in Openshift and currently I need to disable the pages zlib encoding, for get my app working proper.

I tried to edit the file httpd.conf via ssh, but I found a no permission error message for this.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, most files under `~/php` in your Openshift gear will be locked or overridden on app restart.

Looking at `~/php/configuration/etc/php.ini` in a PHP 5.4 OpenShift app I see that zlib compression is disabled at the PHP level:

```
; Transparent output compression using the zlib library
; Valid values for this option are 'off', 'on', or a specific buffer size
; to be used for compression (default is 4KB)
; Note: Resulting chunk size may vary due to nature of compression. PHP
;   outputs chunks that are few hundreds bytes each as a result of
;   compression. If you prefer a larger chunk size for better
;   performance, enable output_buffering in addition.
; Note: You need to use zlib.output_handler instead of the standard
;   output_handler, or otherwise the output will be corrupted.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

So then I presume Apache is compressing the output. See here: [Disabling Apache compression](https://serverfault.com/questions/152756/disabling-apache-compression)